# Greedy Algorithm - Roman Numerals

Tags: c, greedy

I'm trying to implement a C program which converts an integer `n` (between 0 and 1024)  into a Roman numeral by way of a greedy algorithm. I have tried to do this in the following manner:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void convert(int);
int max(int[], int, int);

int main(){

    //User Input
    int n;
    printf("Enter a digit between 0 and 1024: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    //Validation
    while((n < 0)||(n > 1024)){
        printf("That number is not between 0 and 1024. Please try again: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    }

    //Output
    printf("\nAs a Roman numeral, this was written: ");
    if (n == 0) printf("nulla");    //Romans wrote 'nulla' for zero
    else convert(n);

    return 0;
}

void convert(int n){
    //Case n = 0
    if (n == 0)  return;

    else{
        //Case n > 0
        char* romanNums[] = {"I", "IV", "V", "IX", "X", "XL", "L", "XC", "C", "CD", "D", "CM", "M"};
        int arabicNums[] = {1, 4, 5, 9, 10, 40, 50, 90, 100, 400, 500, 900, 1000};
        int biggestNo = max(arabicNums, 12, n); //Biggest number in arabicNums[] smaller than n

        printf("%s", romanNums[biggestNo]); //Print the biggest number as a Roman numeral
        convert(n - biggestNo);             //Convert the remaining

    }
}

//This function determines the maximum number in arr[] smaller than n
int max(int arr[], int size, int n){
    int i, max;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if (n < arr[i]) max = i;
    }
    return max;
}
```

I have tried debugging and modifying aspects of the code, but it's not working. I'd appreciate any feedback.

---

**UPDATE** I've managed to amend my program so that it outputs the values 1, 4, 5 etc. correctly, but composite values (i.e. those which require another iteration of `convert()`) keeps resulting in "Romans.exe not responding". Here is the new code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void convert(int);
int max(int[], int, int);

int main(){

    //User Input
    int n;
    printf("Enter a digit between 0 and 1024: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    //Validation
    while((n < 0)||(n > 1024)){
        printf("That number is not between 0 and 1024. Please try again: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    }

    //Output
    printf("\nAs a Roman numeral, this was written: ");
    if (n == 0) printf("nulla");    //Romans wrote 'nulla' for zero
    else convert(n);

    return 0;
}

void convert(int n){
    //Case n = 0
    if (n == 0)  return;

    else{
        //Case n > 0
        char* romanNums[] = {"I", "IV", "V", "IX", "X", "XL", "L", "XC", "C", "CD", "D", "CM", "M"};
        int arabicNums[] = {1, 4, 5, 9, 10, 40, 50, 90, 100, 400, 500, 900, 1000};
        int biggestNo = max(arabicNums, 13, n); //Biggest number in arabicNums[] smaller than n

        printf("%s", romanNums[biggestNo]); //Print the biggest number as a Roman numeral
        convert(n - arabicNums[biggestNo]); //Convert the remaining

    }
}

//This function determines the maximum number in arr[] smaller than n
int max(int arr[], int size, int n){
    int i, max;
    for(i = size; i > 0; i--){
        if (n <= arr[i]) max = i;
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about how it is not working?

Comment: @MartinBroadhurst I don't think it's terminating - when I run the program stops responding.

Comment: I think the `while` loop is your problem (in `main`).  `n` never changes in the body of that loop, so you'll never leave it in cases where `n` is outside the range you are looking for.

Comment: If a bug causes `n` to become negative, the program will never end. In other words, the code checks for `n==0`, and the comment in the `else` says `n>0`, but nothing checks that `n` is *actually* `>0`.

Comment: @MartinBroadhurst Nothing, it doesn't run :/

Comment: @user3386109 So I can fix that by another validation check right? But what about the algorithm itself? Is it correct?

Comment: @LukeCollins My comment was more of a debugging hint: you could put in an extra `printf("%d\n",n);` at the beginning of the function to see what's happening with `n`. OTOH, in the final production code, I would change the first `if` to `if (n<=0)`. That would terminate the recursion if/when something goes wrong.

Comment: In response to the edit: the loop in `max` should be `for (i = size-1; i >= 0; i--)`. Array indexes go from `0` to `< size` or from `size-1` to `0`.

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 missing point on your code:

On function max:

```
for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
    if (n < arr[i]) max = i;
}
```

must be:

```
for(i = 0; i <= size; i++){
    if (n >= arr[i]) max = i;   // Equal is require. Isn't it?
}
```

On your main function: function convert:

```
convert(n - biggestNo);             //Convert the remaining
```

must be:

```
convert(n - arabicNums[biggestNo]);
```

biggestNo is seq number, not is value for div

Comment: Thanks for those! For some reason, it still doesn't run. (I get a not responding error)

Comment: Are you try to print origin value of n before you call function convert()?

Comment: @LukeCollins, additionally, the sense of the comparison in function `max()` is reversed.  You're looking for the largest element of `arr` that does not exceed `n` -- that corresponds to `arr[i] <= n`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger So it should be `for(i = size; i > 0; i--)`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Eurica! It works. Thank you.

Comment: @LukeCollins: I don't know what "for" you using right now, but dont forget about : 12 is real index you put into function max, so don't forget "=" operator. On your comment, the correct is: `for(i = size; i >= 0; i--)` :)

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a size of 12 to the max function, when the size of the arabicNums array is 13.

Comment: But the counter in the max function starts from 0

Comment: @LukeCollins, but your loop condition is that `i` is strictly less than `size`.

Comment: but passing 12 as an argument to max, the loop finishes in 11, not 12, so it never checks the last element [12].

Comment: You're right there actually. Cheers!